# How to use coalesce with range?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

Using the Grateful Dead graph:

```
g = TinkerFactory.createGratefulDead().traversal()
```

I'd like to first try one `range`, and if it does not result in values, return a different `range`:

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1> coalesce(
......2>   range(900,909),
......3>   range(0,9)
......4> )
```

My expectation is that the first `range` would not find anything since the graph only has 808 vertices, so it would instead return the first 10 items. However, it returns all 808 vertices and seems to ignore `range`. How should I construct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not quite thinking of `coalesce()` the right way. Remember that you're dealing with a stream of "things" flowing through your Gremlin pipeline. In your example you start with `g.V()` which iterates all vertices in the graph. `coalesce()` will be called on each of those vertices. `coalesce()` is designed to return the result from the first traversal argument that produces an output. The first will fail and the second will succeed and output that current vertex as it fits the range of 0 to 9. You can see this in action if you `profile()`:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().coalesce(range(10,20),range(0,1))
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
==>v[3]
==>v[4]
==>v[5]
==>v[6]
gremlin> g.V().coalesce(range(10,20),range(0,1)).profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[])                                             6           6           0.565    66.10
CoalesceStep([[RangeGlobalStep(10,20)], [RangeG...                     6           6           0.290    33.90
  RangeGlobalStep(10,20)                                                                       0.036
  RangeGlobalStep(0,1)                                                 6           6           0.047
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -           0.855        -
```

Not sure if there is another way to do this, but off the top of my head I think you'd have to realize a list with `fold()` so you could iterate it to see if you run out of items and then if you do iterate it again:

```
gremlin> g.V().fold().coalesce(range(local,10,20).unfold(),range(local,0,1).unfold())
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V().fold().coalesce(range(local,10,20).unfold(),range(local,0,2).unfold())
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
gremlin> g.V().fold().coalesce(range(local,5,6).unfold(),range(local,0,2).unfold())
==>v[6]
```

The use of `fold()` will potentially come at some cost as you will need to realize that list in memory. Another option might be to do something like this:

```
gremlin> g.V().order().by(id).range(10,20).fold().coalesce(unfold(),V().order().by(id).range(0,2))
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
gremlin> g.V().order().by(id).range(5,6).fold().coalesce(unfold(),V().order().by(id).range(0,2))
==>v[6]
```

If you can force an order that the graph (depends on the graph you use) will optimize then you only realize a much smaller list in memory.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I think I understand this a little better. Will folding like this potentially introduce a performance issue since it would be operating on the entire set of vertices before it gets limited by range?

Comment: yes - it has the potential to cause problems with performance because you have to realize a list of results in memory to do it, but you're trying to process items in the stream more than one time so i'm not sure what else you can do. i've added another suggestion to my answer